# AWS ECS Network ACL requirements

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I currently have a set up in AWS with something like the following:

[image]

Image source from [task networking in aws fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/task-networking-in-aws-fargate/).

I am using AWS ECR to store my docker image and in my task definition, as container image, I am using the provided URI of the repository. Everything is in the same region and they are working just fine.

However I want to strengthen the security on AWS by whitelisting specific ports only. From security groups point of view, I have updated them as needed and everything is still working as expected. However for Network ACL, I am having some issues with the Fargate task. In ACL section in the public subnet, for inbound rules, I want to allow  access to only HTTPS and HTTP from the internet (0.0.0.0/0). Doing so is resulting into this issue with my fargate task: `ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: pull command failed: : signal: killed`. It is to be noted that the outbound rules for both subnets (private and public) allows traffic to anywhere (0.0.0.0/0).

I understand that the Fargate task needs to connect to the internet to pull the docker image in ECR and the NAT helps do that. `docker pull` or `docker push` uses HTTPS and the private subnet has allowed all traffic from all source and the same for outbound.

NACLs for public subnets
[image]

Please advice on how to amend the Network ACL to whitelist specific ports only.

P.S: The last resort would be to use AWS PrivateLink to access the ECR repository, but I don't want to do that yet.

Comment: Can you provide/screenshot exactly what are yor NACLs? Also I understand that everything works as expected if you use default NACLs?

Comment: Post updated with NACLs applied for public subnets. Yes, everything works fine with default NACLs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your are only allowing ports 80 and 443 in your NACLs. This is **not enough**, as you need to also allow [ephemeral ports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports).

This is because a request to ECR will come back to your container using **ephemeral ports**, not 80 and 443. These two ports are only used for your container to connect to ECR, not for return traffic from ECR to your container.

Comment: thank you so much man, it is working as expected after whitelisting the ephemeral ports.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue if I allow all ingress through ACL and restrict egress to the vpc cidr, https (443) and the ephermal ports (1024-65535). When all egress is allowed things work but we need to restrict it. Do you know what could be missing?